# nextSyncToken is always empty in the list responce

Tags: api, calendar, synchronization, token, instances

I'm trying to make a google sync method from PHP, and i need to receive the nextSyncToken for the initial sync to make it work. And for some reason it's empty.

The connection is made using a access token:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new \Google_Client();
    $this->client->setApplicationName("Stb Agenda 2.0");
    $this->client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)));

    $this->client->setAuthConfig('/var/www/api/WebAgenda-Api/cert/client_secret_dev_api.json');
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
    $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    $this->service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

}

public function authenticate($accessToken){

    $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
        return $this->client->getAccessToken();
    }

}
```

Then i get the events:

```
public function getSyncEvents($calendarId, $syncToken = null)
{

    $options = array(
        'singleEvents' => true,
        'showDeleted' => true
    );
    if($syncToken){
        $options['syncToken'] = $syncToken;
    }

    try {
        $eventObj = $this->service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $options);
    } catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e) {

        $errors = $e->getErrors();

        $fp = fopen("google_sync_log.txt", a);
        fwrite($fp, $e->getCode().' - '.serialize($errors)."\n");
        fclose($fp);

        foreach($errors as $error){
            if($error['reason'] == "fullSyncRequired"){
                $eventObj = $this->service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
            }

        }

    }


    if($eventObj) {

        $events = $eventObj->getItems();

        $nextSyncToken = $eventObj->getNextSyncToken();

        $response = array();
        $response['syncToken'] = $nextSyncToken;
```

The sync toke is null for the first call, and then it should be added, but it's empty also in the response: https://www.screencast.com/t/AZdXQcUNE

And another issue is with the event instances

```
$ev = $this->service->events->instances($calendarId, $event->getId());
$occurrences = $ev->getItems();
```

The items are always empty for all the events: https://www.screencast.com/t/hzHck7a8d . I need to get all the event's occurrences.

If someone has some idea what could be the solution i would greatly appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: for the sync token it was no issue, only for the last page you get the sync token, for all the other calls you get nextPageToken

Comment: it seams that this was an issue only with some very old events that the initial sync was returning, everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

Remove "orderBy" option in $optParams